# How same consumers in same consumer group in multiple service instance work when using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have tested **my service having one instance** using **SeekToCurrentErrorHandler**, which is **having one consumer in one consumer group**. In case of failure, retry happens and the records get committed as I have user **ACK mode as RECORD and did not use ACK mode as MANUAL**, as that creates a problem.

Now, let us have 2 more instances of my service, which has the same consumer with same consumer group.

My question: Are these 2 new instances going to retry like the first instance do exactly the same if in case the records have been committed by the first instance?

```
  ContainerProperties containerProperties = factory.getContainerProperties();
  containerProperties.setAckOnError(false);
  containerProperties.setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
  containerProperties.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
```

[CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSw5Z.png)

[STCEH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1nFc.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple consumers in the same group, each consumer will get a subset of the partitions; each consumer is independent; there is no communication between the instances.

If consumer1 dies during retries and its partition(s) allocated to another consumer, the retries will start from the beginning.

There is no persistent data about retries, just in-memory for the current consumer.

Comment: Thanks Gary. One question - I am using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler. Even i am not using any ACK mode still the offset is getting committed in case of any exception. Please can you help ?

Comment: The offset will not be committed until the retries are exhausted and the recoverer called. You can see all offset activity by setting the `commitLogLevel` container property to INFO. However, with older versions (before 2.3) the `ackOnError` property was `true` by default. It is now `false`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1027 If you are using an older version, set it to `false`.

Comment: `ackOnError` is `false` for me and I have used `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackoff(5000L,5L))`. Still the offset is getting committed after all retries exhausted. Why is it happening when I have not used any `AckMode` `RECORD` or `MANUAL`

Comment: `>Still the offset is getting committed after all retries exhausted.` That's what it is designed to do; you can avoid it by setting `ackAfterHandle` to `false` on the error handler, but it's pointless because if the next record in the the partition is successfully proceessed, the previous offset is implicitly committed. You would have to `stop(() -> { })` or `pause()`  the container in the recoverer to prevent subsequent record processing.